# LinkedIn Federator - Get Network without API

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api

I am looking to fetch degree of my particular connection without API using LinkedIn federator. For e.g. I have a first degree connection named "Vivek Joshi" working in company "ABC". So, I query LinkedIn federator to find the degree which is first("1st") in this case.

Query URL -- https://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=Vivek,Joshi,ABC&types=mynetwork

and I get a JSON response containing degree information. The above URL works only if user is logged in to LinkedIn.

I have asp.net application in which I have "Sign in with LinkedIn" option as available too. But when I authorize any user to LinkedIn through my application and see the response headers of the LinkedIn authorization call, there is a header named as "Set-Cookie" but it doesn't have cookie I'm looking for which is "li_at"(LinkedIn Session Cookie).

The problem is that query url mentioned above expects a request header named as "cookie" with the value of "li_at" cookie.

How can I make the above URL work?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve this information without using the API.  Access to connection data is currently available to select LinkedIn partner developers.  You can learn more about LinkedIn's partner programs here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Comment: Justin, can I use the following URL:

Comment: Justin, can I use this URL:  https://www.linkedin.com/ta/federator?query=Vivek,Joshi,ABC&types=mynetwork  and hit a post request using .net libraries in the back-end to get a JSON response. This JSON response contains the degree information that I'm looking for. But, the problem is that it accepts cookie value as request parameters which is "li_at" in this case. I can fetch this cookie only in local scope i.e. when the application is running on IIS under my system account (system user with which I'm logged in). How can I make this URl work globally? I hope I have made myself clear.